# How to dynamically generate and send jQuery to the webpage from C# AND have it work

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

So, I am dynamically generating jQuery using C# and sending it to the webpage.
**The problem is it appears to be generating correct jQuery according to the file and according to Js Fiddle but it does not actually work on the page.**

The jsFiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/ER2hE/

Now I looked up how to send javacript to the website. It should work like this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx

and my code which does that is this method

```
    private void sendScript(string script)
    {
        const string someScript = "alertMe";
        //send the built script to the website.
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), someScript, script, true);
    }
```

This is super simple it has worked for other pieces of code calling. But it has not for this instance.

The code that calls it is this in my C#

```
    private void populateGroups()
    {
        //this generates correct javascript according to the file and JS fiddle but unfortunately doees not work.

        string splitme = "USE ACES SELECT GroupName, GroupID FROM PrimaryGroup ORDER BY GroupName";
        DataTable dt = fillDataTable(splitme);
        string script = "";

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            //add the locations to the <select> box
            script += " $('#groupList').append('<option value=\" " + dr.ItemArray[1].ToString() + " \"> " + dr.ItemArray[0].ToString() + " </option>');  ";
        }

        sendScript(script);
        JSErrorLog(script, "GROUPS");
}
```

The whole thing is being called on startup

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)                
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            populateMakes();
            populateLocation();
            populateGroups();
        }
    }
```

The jQuery its generating also works in JSFiddle I am pulling this from a method that writes the javascript it generates in a method calling here is the fiddle JSErrorLog.

http://jsfiddle.net/ER2hE/

Oh and my html in my aspx file looks like this

```
    <div class="row2">
       <span>Group</span>
        <select id="groupList" multiple="multiple" onclick="setGroups()" class="normalsize">
        </select>
    </div>
```

I believe that is everything. I just want my stuff to work. I am willing to post any additional code, just ask. If you have an idea as to why its not working, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

When does it actually execute that code? Before or after the element with id "groupList" exists in the DOM? My guess is before.

Solution? Wrap your code inside a document.ready handler.

```
jQuery(function($) {
     $('#groupList').append('<option value=" 46 "> AC Units </option>');
     // etc etc
});
```

Comment: I will certainly give it a try.

Comment: Hmm, I am worried instead it is getting sent before jquery is loaded.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is meaningless. Was an error thrown? Do you have your console open? Are you using a debugger? What browser are you using? Is jQuery actually loading before it hits the first `$`???

Comment: I am using google chrome, the latest version. I have checked my javascript error console, there are no errors. I am using visual studio's debugger for the C# code. I don't know how to tell if jQuery is loaded before the script is executed.

Comment: If you don't know how to tell if jQuery is loaded, that should be your number 1 priority. Use `window.alert(typeof $)` right before your script. Regardless, this isn't the issue, because an error would have appeared in the console. Don't use register startup script, just use an `asp:literal` and set the `.Text` equal to your script.

Answer (score 0):

Return simple string js code. And run it with  eval()